# Vertical carousel on scroll reactjs

Tags: reactjs, scroll, carousel

I want to have a section of the website which is fixed while to slide the carousel on scroll (vertically). Once you are at the last slide the scroll will let you continue on the page instead of changing the slide of the carousel. No idea on how to do this

row with a different background color which remain fixed while the user slides through the carousel slides by scrolling the page. once we arrive on the last slide the scroll will do the usual function on the page

Comment: We need at least what you tried so we can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I really don't know where to begin that the problem